# Does POV-Ray support regular units of measurements like inch, mm?

Tags: povray

I want to translate the camera by 2 inches, but found that POV does not have unit declarations.
Are there any default settings to declare 1=?
If there is none, then how can I translate by 2 inches?

Answer (score 1):

The units in POVRay are arbitrary. If you want to model something in inches, just assume that all coordinates in inches (including the camera).  Then translating by 2 means translating by 2 inches.  You just need to be consistent that all distances are using the same units.  Something that's two feet away has to be entered as 24 if you're assuming that 1 means an inch.  If you want to do feet to inches conversions, you can create macros to do it.